# Can two or more requests be processed exactly at the same time in express?

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency

I'm quite new to this kind of cases. See, I'm building a restful app, based in an express backend and mobile frontend. There are two particular type of users, let's say clients and workers. A client can send a notification to all workers saying that he's looking for a worker, so, all workers get that notification, they must accept or reject it, BUT, only one can be accepted, let's say the fastest pressing the "Accept" button. so, here is my doubt, what happens if two workers press the "Accept" button exactly at the same time and they are received (at the same time too) by express?, are they processed at the same time? or the fact that node is single threaded makes this impossible to happen? I just want to be sure that it is impossible that due to aforesaid two (or more) workers could be assigned to the same client.

I have searched for this in internet but I haven't found anything that could clear my mind with this situation. And I honestly have no idea where to start, so, any suggestions are accepted. I have seen things like queue managers for node (like Bull), but I think they are not the solution for this case, but I'm not sure of this neither, I need at least someone to point me to the right direction to the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use zookeeper or async lock https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-lock . Last thing you want is a race condition.

Comment: Practical advice; well done. You might want to read the [tour]; you're clearly an experienced programmer.

Comment: Thank you!, this is probably the solution I am looking for, at least now I have a good start point

Comment: I finally could check that this actually worked for me, so, I marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple but maybe not as good as lock solution is database transaction. Once the first worker accepts the job, it will add a flag in database. The second worker could have started a database transaction but eventually not able to complete the process since the flag set by previous worker. Then rollback the whole transaction.

Comment: That could actually be a good solution, I will look into this solution and see if it's viable

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using locks, you can't rule out the possibility.

Node might be single-threaded *now* (it isn't), and it might serve one user before moving onto the next (which iirc it doesn't), but if you can't find it written in documentation then it's no assurance at all. There's always the possibility that an upgrade might change the way that it works.

There is, however, a solution. If there's a language feature that guarantees that a resource will be locked and unusable by other instances whilst it's locked, that will give you the assurance you need.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it could not be exactly how we understand "single threaded" language, and also I know that a node update could ruin this. Then probably using a library could be the best option